# Method chaining using javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get method chaining to work using javascript:

```
(function(){
    var first = function(){
        console.log("1st Chain");
        return this;
    };

    var second = function(){
        console.log("2nd Chain");
    }

    first().second();
})();
```

Only the first function is printing to the console but the second function is saying its undefined. However when I tried it using a Constructor, it works.

```
var Chaining = function(){
   this.first = function(){
       console.log("1st Chain");
       return this;
   };

   this.second = function(){
       console.log("2nd Chain");
   };
};

var chain = new Chaining;
chain.first().second(); // this works fine.
```

Comment: Simply log `this` in the first function.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why not call first function in second function?

Comment: You don't quite yet get what `this` is about in javascript.

Comment: This is comparing apples with oranges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first Chain `this` is bound to the window 
and therefore `second` is not visible (`undefined` in that scope).

```
(function(){

    var first = function(){
        console.log("1st Chain");
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    };

    window.second = function(){
        console.log("2nd Chain");
    }

    first().second();
})();
```

To get rid of an export to the global window object of the second function, you could use a Object that's only visible in the Scope of the anonymous function.

```
(function(){

    var Chain = {};

    Chain.first = function(){
        console.log("1st Chain");
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    };

    Chain.second = function(){
        console.log("2nd Chain");
        return this;
    }

    // example
    Chain.first().second().first();

    // example export 
    // window.Chain = Chain;

})();
```

If you want to chain in another scope, you could export your `Chain` to the window and use it without new, ie. `Chain.first().second();`.

You could also save a pointer to this (as pointed out by Jonathon):

```
(function(){

    var self = this;

    this.first = function(){
        console.log("1st Chain");
        console.log(this);
        return self;
    };

    this.second = function(){
        console.log("2nd Chain");
        return self;
    }

    // example
    first().second().first();

    // export example
    // window.Chain = self;
})();

// exported anonymous function to Chain    
// Chain.first().second();
```

Saving a pointer to `this` is sometimes necessary, because the this keyword is scope-changing and refers to the context of the executed function.
`this` does not refer to the instance of the object, where `this` is used, like you would expect in Java.

Every function can therefore bound to another scope.
To adjust the function context use [bind, apply and call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: sorry Im a newbie to javascript, can i ask what is the second function bound to then if its not bound to the window.

Comment: ie. `first` is a function visible in the scope of an anonymous function, i think   [scope and this](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) is an interesting read.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to expose a function into a global scope instead of returning some locally scoped object.

Comment: yeah, i updated the answer to show a slightly better aproach without cluttering the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` in the context of the global object, you make global variables and obliterate them if they already exist. When in doubt, log `this` and if it's the global object...

Don't do this.

Here's an option that gets you the behavior you're looking for:

```
var chaining = function() { 
  return {
    first: function() { 
      console.log("first()");
      return this; 
    },
    second: function() { 
      console.log("second()"); 
    },
    all: function() { 
      this.first().second();
    }
  }
};

chaining().all();

var chain = chaining(); 
chain.first().second();
```

This outputs `first()`, `second()`, `first()`, `second()` as you probably would expect. That's because `this` is used in the context of the object returned by calling `chaining()`.

[More information and good reading about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1):

```
(
  function(){
    var that = this;

    this.first = function () {
      console.log("1st Chain");
      return that;
    };

    this.second = function () {
      console.log("2nd Chain");
      return that;
    }

    first().second();
  }()
);
```